# Adding a value and key into an NSMutableArray - Objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I've read and tried a dozen or more variants of my own question, but still need some help please.

I have a large existing array, and I want to add a new object (key and value) to each record.

This is an element in the incoming array:

`{
     "trip_id": 65,
     "arrival_time": "08:56:08",
     "departure_time": "08:56:08",
     "stop_id": 1161,
     "stop_sequence": 8,
     "stop_headsign": 0
     },`

This is what I want to achieve:

`{
     "trip_id": 65,
     "arrival_time": "08:56:08",
     "departure_time": "08:56:08",
     "stop_id": 1161, 
     "stop_name": "a stop name",
     "stop_sequence": 8,
     "stop_headsign": 0
     },`

This is my code so far -- the commented lines are other attempts:

```
    NSString *nameKey = @"stop_name";
        int i=0;
        for (i=0; i<stopTimesArray.count; i++) {
            NSNumber *stopTimesId = [stopTimesArray[i] valueForKey:@"stop_id"];

            int j=0;
            for (j=0; j<stopArray.count; j++) {
                NSNumber *stopId = [stopArray[j] valueForKey:@"stop_id"];
                if (stopId == stopTimesId) {
                    NSString *stopNameString = [stopArray[j] valueForKey:@"stop_name"];
                    NSLog(@"stopNameString: %@", stopNameString);

                   [outgoingStopTimesDictionary setObject:stopNameString forKey:@"stop_name"];
                   //[outgoingStopTimesArray addObject:outgoingStopTimesDictionary];
                   //[outgoingStopTimesArray addObjectsFromArray:stopTimesArray[i]];

                    //[stopTimesArray[i] addObject:@{@"stop_name":stopNameString}];
//[stopTimesArray[i] addObject:@{@"stop_name":stopNameString}];
                [stopTimesArray[i] addObject: outgoingStopTimesDictionary];
                }
            }

        }

        //NSLog(@"outgoingStopTimesArray: %@", outgoingStopTimesArray);
        //NSLog(@"outgoingStopTimesDictionary: %@", outgoingStopTimesDictionary);
        //NSLog(@"stopTimesArray: %@", stopTimesArray);
```

The error I am getting with approach is:

`stopNameString: S Monroe Street, NB @ 18th Street S, NS
[__NSCFDictionary addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd7f2c22760
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd7f2c22760'`

I'm either getting a null dictionary, or an unrecognised object exception when I try to add the dictionary to my array. Please point me to a working answer, and I'll delete my question.

Comment: 1) You can't use `==` to compare two `NSNumber` objects. 2) Post details about the unrecognized selector error (full message and which line causes it). 3) Do you really need `valueForKey:`? To get a simple value from a dictionary you should use `objectForKey:`.

Comment: The error is clear. `stopTimersArray[i]` is an `NSDictionary`, not a mutable array.

Comment: ok. But then how do I use it to add the new object? I have tried the commented ways shown in my question.

Comment: If you want to add the dictionary to the `stopTimesArray` then add it to the array, not one of the elements of the array: `[stopTimesArray addObject:outgoingStopTimesDictionary];`.

Comment: But I want to add a new object to each of the 30k plus items in the array.

Comment: Sorry but your requirement isn't clear. Show a sample of the data you have and what it should look like when done (update your question with the details - don't post a comment).

Comment: done.. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your goal is to add one new key/value pair to the dictionary at `stopTimesArray[i]`. Here's your code all cleaned up with what I believe you need:

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *stopTimesDictionary in stopTimesArray) {
    NSNumber *stopTimesId = stopTimesDictionary[@"stop_id"];
    for (NSDictionary *stopDictionary in stopArray) {
        NSNumber *stopId = stopDictionary[@"stop_id"];
        if ([stopTimesId isEqual:stopId]) {
            NSString *stopNameString = stopDictionary[@"stop_name"];
            stopTimesDictionary[@"stop_name"] = stopNameString;

            // Uncomment the following line if "stop_id" is unique within the "stopArray"
            // break;
        }
    }
}
```

Since it seems your `stopTimesArray` contains immutable dictionaries, the above code won't work as written. Here is a solution that deals with that:

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < stopTimesArray.count; i++) {
    NSDictionary *stopTimeDictionary = stopTimesArray[i];
    NSNumber *stopTimesId = stopTimesDictionary[@"stop_id"];
    for (NSDictionary *stopDictionary in stopArray) {
        NSNumber *stopId = stopDictionary[@"stop_id"];
        if ([stopTimesId isEqual:stopId]) {
            NSString *stopNameString = stopDictionary[@"stop_name"];
            NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [stopTimesDictionary mutableCopy];
            tempDict[@"stop_name"] = stopNameString;
            [stopTimesArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:tempDict];

            // Uncomment the following line if "stop_id" is unique within the "stopArray"
            // break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but the code  gives me this exception: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
`

Comment: OK, then that means your `stopTimesArray` is an array of `NSDictionary` and not an array of `NSMutableDictionary`. You need to update your code so the dictionaries are mutable. This is outside the code you posted in your question. Another option would be to replace the immutable dictionary in the `stopTimesArray` with a new one containing the added key/value pair. I will update my answer showing that solution.

Comment: hmm. working with both your code snips, (as the second looks like your previous snip). They both result in the same error: 

`NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'`

Comment: My second set of code can't be causing that error. It's quite different from the first set of code. Look again at my second set of code. Make sure you are using `tempDict` and make sure you use `mutableCopy`.

Comment: Well this is embarrassing. After an all nighter, I found that your code would work ok, if only I had initialized the dictionary.

Comment: Someone explain to me why my answer (excluding the OP's own answer) is the only one with a down vote yet my answer is correct and the only one that actually helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
                 dictTo=[NSDictionary new];
                 dictTo =
                 @{
                   @"vPLocationLat" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[[json valueForKey:@"result"] valueForKey:@"geometry"] valueForKey:@"location"] valueForKey:@"lat"]],
                   @"vPLocationLong" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[[json valueForKey:@"result"] valueForKey:@"geometry"] valueForKey:@"location"] valueForKey:@"lng"]]
                   };



                arrLocationList =[NSMutableArray new];
                arrLocationList =[dictTo[@"data"] mutableCopy];
```

## another Solution

-> Try to implement your Code as per in given Code

```
NSMutableArray* newArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray* oldArray = outerDictionary[@"scores"];
for (NSDictionary* dictEntry in oldArray) {
    NSString* leagueCode = dictEntry[@"league_code"];
    if ([leagueCode isEqualToString @"epl"]) {
        [newArray addObject:dictEntry];
    }
}
```

## Another one Solution

Try something like this.

Assume your array is called array and yourNewNameString is your new value for name

```
for(NSMutableDictionary *dict in array){
    if([[dict objectForKey:@"id"]integerValue]==5){
        [dict setObject:yourNewNameString forKey@"name"];
    }
}
```

edit This is assuming you initialized your array with NSMutableDictionarys (Not just NSDictionarys)

Comment: 1) Code-only answers aren't acceptable. Explain what the problem was and how your answer fixes it. 2) What does your code have to do with the OP's problem?

Comment: Please see @rmaddy comment. Your code snippets don't seem to be relevant to my question. Can you revise your answer.

Comment: I do appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
//You can create dictionary and add it into NSMutableArray Object Like..

NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSDictionary *inventory = @{
    @"Mercedes-Benz SLK250" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:13],
    @"Mercedes-Benz E350" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:22],
    @"BMW M3 Coupe" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:19],
    @"BMW X6" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],
};

[arr addObject:inventory];

//You can access using key like...

NSString *strForBMWX6 = [[arr objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"BMW X6"];

// in your case you just miss objectAtIndex:j
```

Comment: Do not use `valueForKey:` to get a value from an `NSDictionary`. Use `objectForKey:`. Only use `valueForKey:` when you have a specific need to use KVC (key-value coding).

Comment: I should have mentioned that the incoming array has 30K+ records.

Answer (score 0):

First, thanks @rmaddy.

I modified his answer a bit, but his was basically correct.

My final code looks like this:

```
  for (NSInteger i = 0; i < stopTimesArray.count; i++) {
        NSDictionary *stopTimesDictionary = stopTimesArray[i];
        NSNumber *stopTimesId = stopTimesDictionary[@"stop_id"];

        for (NSDictionary *stopDictionary in stopArray) {
            NSNumber *stopId = stopDictionary[@"stop_id"];
            if ([stopTimesId isEqual:stopId]) {
                NSString *stopNameString = stopDictionary[@"stop_name"];
                NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [stopTimesDictionary mutableCopy];
                tempDict[@"stop_name"] = stopNameString;
                [outgoingStopTimesArray addObject:tempDict];
                 break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer is nearly identical to the second set of code in my answer. The only difference is the one line where you put `tempDict` and that difference is because you didn't explain your requirements well at all.